# Strange issue with readonly properties for iVars in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

Here is what I have:

```
@interface engine : NSObject
{

    int test;

}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) int test;
```

When I try to assign a value(10) to iVar test within my own class (engine class), the debugger shows test = 10, and _test = 0.

When I try to read from test, I get 0, I'm guessing i'm getting the value of_test.

How do I make it work the way it is supposed to?  I want outside classes to have readonly access to "test", but within my class, I can assign and read values to/from "test"?

Or what is wrong with this implementation?

UPDATE:I do no syntesize as I use xcode 4.4 which automatially does it for you.  I assume the synthesize will use the same iVar name as the property.  Which is the default behaviour anyways if you do a normal synthesize.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic synthesize creates an instance variable with a underscore prefix, so a property called `test` generates a backing instance variable of `_test`. So you have two instance variables; `test`, which isn't connected to the property, and `_test`. If you write to the instance variable `test`, it will not be reflected in `_test` or the property's value.

But more to the point, declaring the backing instance variable yourself is pointless. It's just an extra code and unnecessary redundancy. The `@property` line already contains type, name, whether it's read/write or read-only and a storage qualifier. Just skip declaring the backing instance variable yourself and use the one the compiler generates for you.

In Engine.h:

```
@interface Engine : NSObject
@property (readonly, assign) NSInteger test;
- (void)doSomething;
@end
```

In Engine.m:

```
@implementation Engine

- (void)doSomething {
    _test++; // _test is created automatically by the compiler
}

@end
```

In other.m:

```
Engine *engine = [[Engine alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%d", engine.test); // 0
[engine doSomething];
NSLog(@"%d", engine.test); // 1
```

This all just works. Don't add to it.

Comment: But my purpose to declare the iVar and then a readonly property is because I want to access the iVar within my class, and the readonly property to be used outside the class.  So is it not possible to do this?  Otherwise I will have to create an accessor myself, and not use the property to achieve the same effect.    But if I can use property it is very convenient.

Comment: Yes. Declare the property, but **do not synthesize or specify an instance variable**. Outside of the class, you can use the property. Inside, you can use the automatically generated instance variable. The compiler knows it exists.

Comment: Have another look. I've added an example.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say without seeing your code, but I am guessing, that you are trying to do something like `test=10` instead of `self.test=10`. Depending on the version of ObjC/XCode you use and on a possible `@synthesize` statement, you are accessing a (whereever defined) local variable, but not the property resp. it's iVar.

**EDIT**

When you want to write a readonly property, you should use its iVar. E.g., after `_test=10` both read accesses, `self.test` and `_test` (but not pure `test`!) should provide the same value.

Comment: If I go self.test = 10, the compiler would give an error saying it is readonly property.  I'm guessing when I try to read from this, it gives me the _test, but when I write to it it writes to test.  But why would it return me the value of _test?

Answer (score 1):

You assume wrong.  The default implementation is to produce the property name with an under bar.  If you want a different name you will need to synthesize it yourself.